# Double vs Two vs Duo

Tags: difference, word-difference

I've noticed that with different words the words **double**, **two**, and **duo** work differently. Why so and how different are they? Are they interchangeable?

- A double-barrel shotgun (why not a two-barrel or duo-barrel)
- A duo-core processor (why not a double-core or a two-core)
- A two-headed giant (why not a double-headed or a duo-headed)

Sometimes I also see the words **pair** and **dual** used in the same way.

- A pair-legged creature.
- A dual-color gradient.

Comment: You might even see *dual* as well.

Comment: @LucianSava Yeh, I'll add it to the question.

Comment: I've never seen "duo core", but "Dual-core" and "Core Duo".  **Dual** is an adjective, **duo** a noun. Nor have I seen "pair-legged".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **double** barrel
>   **double**-headed eagle

is used to signify a second but distinct copy, in a double barrel gun, both barrels are operated independently.

> **duo** core
>   dynamic **duo**

implies there is some communication or coordination between the two parts so they act as a single unit even though there are two parts, in the case of duo core processors, there is *load balancing*.  In the case of *dynamic duo* there is coordination between Batman and Robin.

> **two** headed

it seems to be the tradition to usually "*count*" the number of body parts. It is also the case that the two heads act independently

> Cerberus is a **three** headed dog
>   Hydra is a **nine** headed snake
>   Cyclops is  **one** eyed giant
>   a **three** legged race

but of course there are exceptions

> **double**-headed eagle

Comment: What about the other two. And are they all basically interchangeable?

Comment: In your examples, not really. "Double barrel" is a set phrase, "*duo* barrel" is not. "Duo core" is a set technical phrase, they are all part of the jargon of describing what they are.  You could possibly say "*dual* barrel" or "*dual* core" which would be understandable. Note that "*duo* core" is a branding name by Intel for their "dual processor".

Comment: What about pair?

Answer (score 0):

I think this can help. 
[double](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=double),
[duo](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=duo), 
[two](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=two), 
Each of these three words means "two". But relation between "one" and "one" in each one of them is different.